# When I delete one product from product table. The all products of that category are not shown

Tags: php, html

I have this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM product 
inner join product_category_r on product_name=pc_product_fk
inner join category on pc_category_fk=category_name 
WHERE category_name='$category'
```

When I delete one product from product table. The all products of that category are not shown. And from product_category_r table, the productname and category name is also deleted. But I am not deleting any record from product_category_r.
Here is my delete query:

```
DELETE FROM product WHERE product_id='$id'
```

Comment: When I add a new product of that category, All previous products are again shown.

Comment: Please edit your question to include all information instead of adding more info as comments.

Comment: check the relationships and joins you performed